# ROS/ROS2 installation on Ubuntu jammy main - Error - jammy release does not have a release file, How to rectify this issue?

Tags: 22.04, locale

```
sdrs@sdrs-ThinkCentre-M90p:~$ locale  # check for UTF-8

sudo apt update && sudo apt install locales
sudo locale-gen en_US en_US.UTF-8
sudo update-locale LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

locale  # verify settings
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_IN:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
Hit:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:4 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Err:5 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2605:bc80:3010::134 80]
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                               
E: The repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
  en_US.ISO-8859-1... done
  en_US.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_IN:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

**My ubuntu Configuration:**

```
sdrs@sdrs-ThinkCentre-M90p:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Comment: Since I'm new around here, Could you please walk me through this?

Comment: Basically http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/ says they don't support 22.04 (`jammy`) yet. Either remove the repo, or switch to 20.04.

Comment: So if i remove that repo, will it work?